# Difficulty with IF/ELSE command on Selenium IDE for successful login flow

Tags: if-statement, selenium-ide

I am very new at using Selenium and I don't have much coding knowledge so I started working on IDE to learn. I am currently working on a flow of commands using Selenium IDE v 3.17.2 for successful login. My aim is to use the VerifyElementPresent command for the logout button and IF/ELSE If the logout button is present, I want the user to proceed with the next test case. However, if the logout button is not present, I want the user to be redirected to the login button.

I tried IF / ELSE condition.
If I'm not logged in, the test will be executed successfully, however if I am logged in, than it will still direct me to enter credentials for login.
Commands I followed:
Open website
VerifyElementPresent: Logout button, value: statusOk
If: "${!statusOk}==false"
Open: login page
Type: email
Type: password
Click: Login
Else if: "${!statusOk}==true"
end
Open: next test case